# How to copy column from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to do a pandas-like operation where you add a column to an existing dataframe which is a copy of a column from another dataframe like so:

```
df[A] = df2[A]
```

When I do this, I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

Looking for workarounds that are preferably not computationally heavy.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747589/copying-a-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-gives-nan-values.

Comment: Hi really think that here index matter. If `df` and `df2` are split in npartition and division is not known how do you know where to attach the new data?

Comment: @SwethaShanmugam found my solution in that post. Thank you.