# Getting NaN values when assigning dataframe columns, and not sure why

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe that reads from a github url. The dataframe then sorts the 'Age' column from the github file into the new dataframe with the values of age being between (1-12) for the 'AGE_12' column and the values of age being between (13-19) for the 'AGE_TEEN' column. However, when I assign the data that represents the 'AGE_12' and 'AGE_TEEN' values to their columns in the new dataframe, I end up getting `NaN` values for them? I tried switching the column positions around and either 'AGE_12' sometimes produces correct values, but not the other, or vice versa.

Here is my code:

```
#Reads url for Github
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/titanic/train.csv'
#Creates dataframe from Raw Github Link 
data = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)



AGE_12 = data[data['Age'].between(1,12)]
AGE_TEEN = data[data['Age'].between(13,19)]


pasUpto19 = pd.DataFrame()
pasUpto19 = pasUpto19.assign(PCLASS=data['Pclass'],AGE_12=AGE_12['Age'],AGE_TEEN=AGE_TEEN['Age'])
print(pasUpto19)
```

It outputs this:

```
     PCLASS  AGE_12  AGE_TEEN
0         3     NaN       NaN
1         1     NaN       NaN
2         3     NaN       NaN
3         1     NaN       NaN
4         3     NaN       NaN
..      ...     ...       ...
886       2     NaN       NaN
887       1     NaN      19.0
888       3     NaN       NaN
889       1     NaN       NaN
890       3     NaN       NaN
```

Sorry in advance if I did something silly, I'm very new to python and using pandas

Comment: check index of your Series

Comment: It looks normal to me, for example `AGE_TEEN` has `NaN` where the subject is not a teen (age not between 13 and 19)? Is it not what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, that actually makes sense, I'm not sure why I thought that it was wrong. I'm trying to make it only display the values that are teen though, how would I go about that?

Comment: You can add this `pasUpto19 = pasUpto19.dropna(subset=['AGE_12', 'AGE_TEEN'], how='all')`

Comment: You already have it, do `AGE_TEEN[['Pclcass', 'Age']]`

Comment: I'm still encountering the same issue @talatccan , it doesn't seem to be dropping the values from it.

Comment: Shape of AGE_12 and AGE_TEEN is not equal. That's why there are NaN values. There are 69 row for AGE_12 and 95 row for AGE_TEEN. If you use the code i wrote than you will have dataframe with 164 rows which includes only AGE_TEEN and AGE_12.

Comment: You're encountering the issue on assignment because the indices of 'AGE_12' and 'AGE_TEEN' are misaligned. (See how 'AGE_12', 'AGE_TEEN' partition the indices from the original dataframe 'data'). Same very common pitfall as [Copying a column from one DataFrame to another gives NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747589/copying-a-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-gives-nan-values) ... the solution is to `reset_index()` on the dataframes...

Comment: ...but ultimately what your code really intends to do here is [(Binning the 'age' column into [1,13), [13,20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273731/binning-a-column-with-pandas) using `pd.cut(data['Age'], [0,12,19,199])`, then `df.groupby()`

Comment: See pandas user guide on [Group-by: split-apply-combine paradigm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) for examples

Answer (score 0):

`pasUpto19 = pasUpto19.dropna(axis=0, how='all')` will drop all nan values from your new dataframe.

Comment: When I try that, I get this:                                                                                          
        ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Try data = data.fillna(0) first then convert the data type of the age column

Comment: I tried that, and the error went away, but I still get the same output as before.

Comment: To check your dtype, do data.dtype and if you see that your age column is an object, then you need to convert it since you are treating the column as numeric value.  I believe you can also use pd.to_numeric(data['age']) to convert the column.

Comment: I did data.dtype and it is an object, but pd.to_numeric(data['age']) didn't do anything either. I feel like I may be doing something horribly wrong with my code.

Comment: Try data['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Age']).  Since it's case sensitive, you need to capitalize the A in age

Comment: Same thing still happens when I do that sadly

Comment: `data['Age12'] = [x if (x > 1) & (x < 12) else '' for x in data['Age']]`

`data['Teen'] = [x if (x > 13) & (x < 19) else '' for x in data['Age']]`

Comment: When I said the same thing happens, I meant the output stays the same as the one I posted in the question, with the NaN values and all. I tried the code you just gave and it returns this error :   SyntaxError: can't assign to comparison

Comment: Ah, I think you just need to do `pasUpto19 = pasUpto19.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`

Comment: That did it, thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Great! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

(You're encountering the issue on assignment **because the indices of 'AGE_12' and 'AGE_TEEN' are misaligned** (see how 'AGE_12', 'AGE_TEEN' partition the indices from the original dataframe 'data'. So they are disjoint; they don't overlap). The hacky solution is to `reset_index()` on the dataframes 'AGE_12','AGE_TEEN' before assigning or concat'ting.
Same very common pitfall as [Copying a column from one DataFrame to another gives NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747589/copying-a-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-gives-nan-values))

But the intent behind your code is that you want to bin (quantize) the 'Age' column:

```
data['Age_binned'] = pd.cut(data['Age'], [0,1,12,20,199])

data['Age_binned'].value_counts(ascending=True)
Age_binned
(0, 1]        14
(1, 12]       55
(12, 20]     110
(20, 199]    535
```

Then, you can use [split-apply-combine paradigm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) with groupby():

```
data.groupby('Age_binned', observed=True)#... then chain into e.g. .agg(), .apply(), .assign(), .transform, .pipe(), etc. See the split-apply-combine doc.
```

And if you wanted to do that binning plus the groupby as a one-liner, without declaring 'Age_binned' column:

```
data.groupby(pd.cut(data['Age'], [0,1,12,19,199]), observed=True)#...
```