# Adding dataframe with different index to time series

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series like

```
             var
date 
2020-03-10   77
2020-03-11   88
2020-03-12   99
```

and I have another dataframe of exact same size of the above time series

```
        mean 
0        12
1        13
2        14
```

I want to add this mean column to the above time series like

```
             var    mean
date 
2020-03-10   77      12
2020-03-11   88      13
2020-03-12   99      14
```

I tried searching but havent got any results.

Comment: See also [Copying a column from one DataFrame to another gives NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45747589/2173773)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign numpy array for prevent data alignment (what create column filled missing values, because different index values):

```
df1 = df1.assign(mean = df2['mean'].to_numpy())
```

Or:

```
df1['mean'] = df2['mean'].to_numpy()
```

Another idea is change index in `df2` same like `df1`, so is possible use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = df2.set_index(df1.index)
df1 = df1.join(df2)
```