# Concat rows from two dataframe with muliple column with different names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes with different column number and rows:

```
con = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1000),
                            'B': range(1000),
                            'C': range(1000),
                            'D': range(1000),
                            'E': range(1000),
                            'F': range(1000)})
st = pd.DataFrame({'G': range(100),
                      'H': range(100),
                      'I': range(100),
                      'J': range(100),
                      'K': range(100)})
```

I would like to concat `con` dataframe (starting from the second column) with `st` dataframe in `con_st` dataframe, discarding the first column from `con` and appending values from the second onwards.

I tried this code:

```
con = con.iloc[:, 1:]
con_st = pd.concat([con, st], ignore_index=True)
```

However, in this way the result is adding columns. I guess the problem is the different column names. There is a way to append data only according to the column indexing?

Answer (score 2):

Two requirements to make this solution work:

1. drop the first column in your first dataframe "con" (you can either use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and slice, or use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and specify the first column)
2. you will then need to rename the columns of the second dataframe "st" so that the DataFrames are *alignable* by column name (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747589/copying-a-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-gives-nan-values)).

Once these are done, you can call [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
res = pd.concat([
    con.iloc[:, 1:], st.set_axis(con.columns[1:1+st.shape[1]], axis=1)]) 
print (res)

     B   C   D   E   F
0    0   0   0   0   0
1    1   1   1   1   1
2    2   2   2   2   2
3    3   3   3   3   3
4    4   4   4   4   4
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95  95  95  95  95  95
96  96  96  96  96  96
97  97  97  97  97  97
98  98  98  98  98  98
99  99  99  99  99  99

[1100 rows x 5 columns] # success!
```

Setting `ignore_index` was not sufficient for your use case as it ignores the index of the input dataframes rather than force alignment (is equivalent to calling `reset_index` on the result)